# Double slash in GPath expression

Tags: gpath

In XPath I can use double slash to express I want to get any node within document, no necessary a child ofa root node, e.g.

```
//input
```

would stand for any `<input>` tag in my XML document.

How do I express it with GPath expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `//` is replaced by `'**'` in GPath.

So your query would be:

`'**'.input`

Link to GPath documentation [here](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_speed_things_up_with_breadthfirst_and_depthfirst).

Comment: Review queue comment: This seems to be a correct answer (I am not familiar), but it would be better with some supporting documentation.